# Sort half of a String ArrayList based on a substring of each string

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I have a String ArrayList of sizes, for example

[12, 10L, 10, 10R, 10S, 10L]

The output should be

[10S, 10R, 10L, 10, 12]

So basically sizes must be first sorted by number - (1,2,3,4,5 ... etc) then by letters.

I managed to get the numbers to sort, so my current output for the input above is

10L, 10, 10R, 10S, 10L, 12

if a letter is missing, then it is the largest (see output above - 10 is after 10L - 10S < 10R < 10L < 10 < 12. )

How should i code a comparator that allows me to do this?

Consider an input array, sizes. This array contains product sizes in the format AB, where:

A is a mandatory integer B is an optional character in [S,R,L] Sizes must first be ordered from smallest to largest by A, and then by B in the order S

Comment: There's a good chance that the correct approach is to parse each `String` into a dedicated class that represents what it is an extends `Comparable` to provide the correct `compare` method. Also, why should S be smaller than R and R smaller than L? Alphabetically it's exactly the other way around, so what are the rules here?

Comment: Those are the rules, Small,Regular and Large, i should have mentioned its for clothes that is why they are like this

Comment: Where would "12S" fall in the above example? Between "10" and "12"? Or between "10L" and "10"?

Comment: Consider an input array, sizes. This array contains product sizes in the format AB, where:

A is a mandatory integer
B is an optional character in [S,R,L]
Sizes must first be ordered from smallest to largest by A, and then by B in the order S<R<L. If B is missing, this is considered to be larger than if B is present. For example, 10S < 10R < 10L < 10 < 12.

So 12S would be after "10", because it first gets sorted by the integers (which i managed with a custom comparator)

Comment: @Mivakes: it's probably cleanest to write a `Size` class that implements `Comparable<Size>`. Then get rid of `List<String>` and use `List<Size>` instead.

Comment: For this current exercise I can't create new classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it works for your testcases. We can always refine it if needed. (Added a helper method)

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("12","10L","10","10R","10S","10L","14L","14","8","12S"));
List<String> orderArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("S", "R", "L"));

List<String> sortedList = list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(str -> Integer.parseInt(((String)str).replaceAll("[A-Z]*","")))
                    .thenComparing(str -> getAnInt(orderArray, (String) str)))
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(sortedList);

private int getAnInt(List<String> orderArray, String str) {
    int i = orderArray.indexOf(str.substring(str.length() - 1));
    if (i == -1) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    return i;
}
```

Output: [8, 10S, 10R, 10L, 10, 12S, 12, 14L, 14]

if you don't want to use streams:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("12","10L","10","10R","10S","10L","14L","14","8","12S"));
List<String> orderArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("S", "R", "L"));

list.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            int lInt = Integer.parseInt(lhs.replaceAll("[A-Z]*", ""));
            int rInt = Integer.parseInt(rhs.replaceAll("[A-Z]*", ""));
            if (lInt != rInt) {
               return lInt - rInt;
            } else {
                return getAnInt(orderArray, lhs) - getAnInt(orderArray, rhs);
            }
        }
    });

System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: its just the streams that wouldnt work in java 7, otherwise the basic idea is the same. You can use loops instead of streams

Comment: @Mivakes updated the answer to not use streams. Try that

Comment: `Arrays.asList` does already return a `List`. There is no need to copy the list via `new ArrayList(…)`. Further, not to use Streams doesn’t imply that you have to implement the `Comparator` via an anonymous inner class. And don’t use minus to implement a `Comparator`, as minus can overflow. Use `Integer.compare(…,…)`. You can avoid the type casts by declaring an explicit parameter type for the first lambda and `comparingInt` might be more efficient here: `Comparator.comparingInt((String str) -> Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[A-Z]*","")))
.thenComparingInt(str -> getAnInt(orderArray, str))`

Comment: Additionally, since `getAnInt` assumes the fixed format of having one letter after the number, the previous step might use the same assumption like `Comparator.comparingInt((String str) -> Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)))` instead of an expensive regex replacement operation. By the way, `getAnInt` can be implemented as simple as `return orderArray.indexOf(str.substring(str.length() - 1)) + Integer.MIN_VALUE;`, which will return numbers having the desired relation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `finalList` list has the sort data.

```
10L, 10, 10R, 10S, 10L, 12
```

Use regex to match the integer, merge the list of `alphanumerics` and `numbers`.

On your sorted list, run this

```
List<String> numberList= new ArrayList<String>(); // store number list
List<String> sizeList= new ArrayList<String>(); // store alphanumerics
for(String value: finalList){

  if(!value.matches("[0-9]+")){  // if contains characters
     sizeList.add(value);
   }
   else{
        numberList.add(value);
  }
}

sizeList.addAll(numberList);
```

`sizeList` has what you need

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct as it might have been due to my bad explanation, i should have copied and pasted what i did above in the edit

It just returns the list the same way as before

Comment: `I managed to get the numbers to sort, so my current output for the input above is
10L, 10, 10R, 10S, 10L, 12` store this result in finalList which is List<String>

Comment: are you checking sizeList? it will have the sorted list

Comment: @Mivakes let me fix it...just give me 2 mins

Comment: I fixed it, tested the output as well.. I changed the regex and it gives correct output. actually previously, i was checking if the number if alphanumeric or not..10 is a valid alpha numeric character as well as valid integer that's why it was always going in the first check.